# how to simplfy this code

Tags: javascript, string

What would be a good way to do this. I have a string with lots of "&lt;" and &gt; and I want to replace them with < and >. So i wrote this:

```
var str = &lt;/text&gt;&lt;word34212&gt;
var p = str.replace('\&lt\;','\<');
var m = p.replace('\&gt\;','\>');
```

but that's just doing the first instance of each - and subsequent instances of &lt;/&gt; are not replaced. I considered first counting the instances of the &lt; and then looping and replacing one instance of the code on every iteration...and then doing the same for the &gt; but obviously this is quite long-winded.

Can anyone suggest a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace multiple occurances you use a regular expression, so that you can specify the global (g) flag:

```
var m = str.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
```

Answer (score 4):

Taken from: http://www.bradino.com/javascript/string-replace/

> The JavaScript function for String
>   Replace replaces the first occurrence
>   in the string. The function is similar
>   to the php function str_replace and
>   takes two simple parameters. The first
>   parameter is the pattern to find and
>   the second parameter is the string to
>   replace the pattern with when found.
>   The javascript function does not
>   Replace All...
>
> To ReplaceAll you have to do it a
>   little differently. To replace all
>   occurrences in the string, use the g
>   modifier like this:

```
str = str.replace(/find/g,”replace”)
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks all. I did google this! Must learn REGEX properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the global modifier:

```
var p = str.replace(/\&lt\;/g,'\<');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use de /g modifier in your regex and it'll work. Check this page for an example : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

I thing a associative array  [regex -> replacement] and one iteration would do it